Mariadb connector to python 3.12.3 in Ubuntu server 24.04 - python3-mariadb package not found?
After updating my system to Ubuntu 24.04 (which includes Python 3.12.3), my code using import mariadb no longer works - the module is not found.
When I try to pip3 install mariadb, I get a message saying that this is an "externally managed environment" and that I should try "apt install python3-xyz", where xyz is my package.
However, "apt install python3-mariadb" can't find a package either. Mariadb is available on my system; systemctl status mariadb returns mariadb version 10.11.7. How can I reinstall the binding?

Could you provide the error that you get when running pip install mariadb? What if you run python -m pip install mariadb?

When I run pip3 install mariadb I get:  error: externally-managed-environment
× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.  ..... then it continues with a story over  non-Debian packages and non-Debian packaged python...  too much to put here..    with python -m pip install mariadb .... I get the same error message

Does this help you out?

Looks like something to try ... I'll let you know what happens...(tomorrow - or so).
